# Función con indexOf

Tags: javascript, function

tengo un ejercicio donde se tiene que crear una función llamada menciona, que recibirá dos parámetros: un *texto* —que es donde vamos a buscar— y una *palabra* —que es la que vamos a averiguar si se menciona en el texto—. La misma función retorna *true* en el caso de encontrar la palabra.

```
function menciona(texto, palabra) { 
if (texto.indexOf(palabra)) {
    return "true"
}else {
    return "false"
}
}
```

Me tira error *Al llamar a la función menciona("Hola mundo","Hola") debe retornar true*. Que puede ser?. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código está checando un valor condicional de texto.indexOf(palabra); pero el método indexOf regresa el índice dentro del arreglo; y cuando no lo encuentra regresa un -1, así que tu función debe de revisar que el método no regrese -1, pues cuando se habla de condicionales un 0 es negativo, pero en índices, 0 es la primera posición del arreglo

Tu código debería de verse así:

```
function menciona(texto, palabra) { 
if (texto.indexOf(palabra) != -1) {
    return "true"
}else {
    return "false"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia todo lo del if por return text.includes(palabra);

```
function menciona(texto, palabra) { 
   return texto.includes(palabra);
}
```